# Creating repeated line charts for individual row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, charts

I have follow type of data in excel sheet and I want to create line charts (for individual team) to show the progress over the month (monthly updated). Is there a way to automate this so that I don't have to select months/year and Team to create the chart for each team? I am not very familiar with VBA but if any expert can share the code, I can try. Or if it is doable with excel macros? Many thanks.

```txt
        | Jan-22  | Feb-22  |  Mar-22  | Apr-22 |  May 2022 |
        |---------|---------|----------|--------|-----------|
TeamA   | 33      | 38      |  45      | 49 83  |  50       |
TeamB   | 1005    | 1085    |  1090    | 1900   |  1920     |
TeamC   | 0.69    | 0.11    |  0.99    | 0.85   |  0.01     |
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmvIo.png)

Answer (score -2):

1. You can try the sparklines in excel:
   [image]
2. Or this may help. You can watch the method in this video.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ody_09oUaHY&ab_channel=MyOnlineTrainingHub
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_p8hltGY4s&ab_channel=KarinaAdcock

Comment: Sorry no, this didn't serve the purpose. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Please see my new answer.

Comment: If you had actually watched the video, you would have known that it was all about creating a separate line chart for each row.  @ClinicalInfo

Comment: I watched the full video. Its useful as an alternative to sparklines. It does create a line chart individually, but my requirement is full line chart where data points are readable and trends can be identified. Sort of presentation material.